# Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 grub doesn't show up only can get to Ubuntu by F9 boot options

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 version 1703, on my HP-15-bw0xx, and made `/boot`, `/`, `/home` partitions. After few initial boots Grub stopped showing up. So when I press ESC button during power-up and then press F9 button which shows boot options as in this image:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Open UEFI settings and put back Ubuntu as the first boot option.

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBay UEFI boot order only shows Notebook hard drive,then USB diskette and other  stuff.

Comment: @DavidFoerster How do I rub Boot-Info?

Comment: What about actually reading the included link above? With the boot-info we can know how it was installed.

Comment: Please visit the link in my previous comment for instructions how to run Boot-Info.